# Modified laptop power supply pulses - voltage too low?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I have modified a laptop switching power supply by changing the voltage divider (as seems to be the standard way to do so), using a potentiometer so I could dial in exactly the right voltage - in my case, a hair under 5 volts.

Normally, it makes the typical high-pitched hum, almost inaudible with the case on. As I turned the pot to lower the voltage, that hum got lower and more click-y, finally reaching a couple clicks per second as I homed in on ~5V. Obviously the sound of the *switching* power supply acting as it's named. But hey, multimeter said it was fine, right?

Upon hooking up a string of 5-volt RGB LEDs (~1A draw initially, all blue), I discovered that they pulse in time with that clicking. That's the issue I hope to understand. I've tried changing the output buffer capacitors to something 50% beefier, but absolutely no change. I thought maybe it could just be the response lag of the feedback circuit, but half a second is practically eons to electronics... at least in the digital circuits I'm used to.

Is this a normal/expected issue? Google doesn't seem to think anyone's even tried to drop a laptop supply this low, let alone any reports of problems.

Comment: better off with an old ATX supply rather than operating below the design parameters

Answer (score 1):

The clicking sound you hear is coming from transformer. If you hold tight the ferrites with your hand then you'll see that the click sound will be lowered.

I personally don't recommend decreasing the output voltage of a flyback converter like you have to such a low voltage. Because its transformer is designed to provide about 19VDC. Playing with feedback resistors can be acceptable for a little change. But you decrase the output voltage about %74! If you really want to get 5VDC, you should also un-wind a few turns from secondary of the transformer.